# MSBuild.exe gives errors about Nuget package conflicts, what does it mean?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, msbuild

Working in VS2017 I have a C# project .Net 4.6 using several Nuget packages. On my dev machine from within VS it builds just fine, I've tested it will restore Nuget packages from completely clean and build correctly.

On our build machine it is build using MSBuild.exe and now everything is going wrong.

> Build>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" ".sln"
> /p:Configuration="Release" /p:Platform="Any CPU" /p:version=4.2.0.3230
> /m "  Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.7.179.6572 for .NET
> Framework Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

I can see the /packages sub-dir is getting populated as expected with packages but then I get errors like:

> Encountered conflict between 'Reference:System.Numerics.Vectors,
> Version=4.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a,
> processorArchitecture=MSIL' and
> 'Platform:System.Numerics.Vectors.dll'.  Could not determine winner
> because 'Reference:System.Numerics.Vectors, Version=4.1.4.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a,
> processorArchitecture=MSIL' does not exist.
> Encountered conflict between 'Platform:System.Numerics.Vectors.dll' and
> 'Reference:System.Numerics.Vectors, Version=4.1.4.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL'.  Could
> not determine winner because 'Reference:System.Numerics.Vectors,
> Version=4.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a,
> processorArchitecture=MSIL' does not exist.

```
My project file looks like:
    <Reference Include="System.Numerics" />
    <Reference Include="System.Numerics.Vectors, Version=4.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>packages\System.Numerics.Vectors.4.5.0\lib\net46\System.Numerics.Vectors.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
```

[image]

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2106,5):
> warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate
> the assembly "log4net, Version=2.0.8.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=669e0ddf0bb1aa2a, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to
> make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required
> by your code, you may get compilation errors.
> []
> For SearchPath "{HintPathFromItem}".
> Considered "packages\log4net.2.0.8\lib\net45-full\log4net.dll", but it didn't
> exist.

I mean, here it is:
[image]

```
<Reference Include="log4net, Version=2.0.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=669e0ddf0bb1aa2a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>packages\log4net.2.0.8\lib\net45-full\log4net.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Every build is a completely clean build (it's wiped between) so I can clearly see Nuget *has* downloaded log4net.dll

I am getting loads of these and I cannot see any explanation why, or where to start looking for a solution. Everything looks to be where it should be

Answer (score 1):

You can try changing a binding redirect in your config file to 2.8.0 of log4net

```
<dependentAssembly>
<assemblyIdentity name="log4net" publicKeyToken="669e0ddf0bb1aa2a" culture="neutral" />
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.8.0" newVersion="2.0.8.0" />
```

Comment: Is app.config used at all during _build_? I thought it was only relevant at runtime?

Comment: The process of locating and binding to an assembly begins when the runtime attempts to resolve a reference to another assembly. This reference can be either static or dynamic. The compiler records static references in the assembly manifest's metadata at build time. Here is the link for more elaboration (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/deployment/how-the-runtime-locates-assemblies)

Comment: I can confirm this wasn't the cause (I actually already have this in my app.config)

Comment: I think you could try `gacutil /i <the path of the dll>` in CMD(run as administrator).