# How to deal with relative HintPath for Nuget dependency assemblies?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, nuget

[This issue](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/738) describes in more detail and discusses the problem I was describing in a [recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62780419/msbuild-exe-gives-errors-about-nuget-package-conflicts-what-does-it-mean?noredirect=1#comment111038584_62780419) - a project was in multiple solutions and the `<HintPath>` was to a local packages directory. So depending which solution was being built, it ran into dependency confusion issues.

Does anyone know of a good workaround? It can't be unusual to have the same project in multiple solutions and it seems crazy that Nuget, which is supposed to help avoid dependency hell, is relying on fragile local paths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does anyone know of a good workaround? It can't be unusual to have the
> same project in multiple solutions and it seems crazy that Nuget,
> which is supposed to help avoid dependency hell, is relying on fragile
> local paths.

I think you could change the [repositoryPath path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file#config-section) in `nuget.config` file so that the hintpath will uses packages under the global nuget caches rather than copy the packages again under your solution folder. This relieves nuget package dependency.

Open `C:\Users\xxx(current user name)\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.Config` and then add these in it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<config>
<add key="repositoryPath" value="%USERPROFILE%\.nuget\packages" />
</config>

</configuration>
```

Then restart VS and it will reference the packages directly from the global nuget caches.

Then run `update-pacakges -reinstall` under **Tools**-->**Nuget Package Manager**-->**Package Manager Console** to uses the new **Hintpath**.

**Besides**, use [PackageReference nuget management format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files) will avoid this behavior and you will not bother by the complex Hintpath problems. It is a new nuget package management format and much easier.

Right-click on the `packages.config` file--> `migrate packages.config to PackageReference`.

And **Note** that when you migrate into Build Server, and if you only build it by command line, you should run `nuget restore xxx.sln` to restore these packages. See [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore#restore-using-the-nugetexe-cli).